# Creating a New JSONObject in android studio returns a null object

Tags: java, android, json, mockito

I am working on a Mockito project where I want to mock a volley class that sends and returns JSON objects. I wrote a simple test method just to make sure I was creating my JSON objects correctly and to my dismay, I found that when I use the constructor in this way `JSONObject testObject = new JSONObject();` and then use `testObject.put("Boolean", true)` and then print out the boolean value of that testObject, the program returns false, instead of true.

```
     @Test
public void testMethod() throws JSONException{
    JSONObject testObject = new JSONObject();
    testObject.put("Boolean", true);
    System.out.println(testObject.getBoolean("Boolean"));
}
```

Here are the import statements I am using for this class

```
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.junit.Rule;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnit;
    import org.mockito.junit.MockitoRule;
```

Any ideas of what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you sent and the value printed true to me. The only difference I can think of is trying

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

instead of

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

To see if something changes